# General method to find the dimension of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

A assume $V$ is the vector space of all $2 \times 2$ matrices over the field $\mathbb F$,find a basis of $V$ with four elements and from there conclude that the dimension of $V$ is $4$.

---

One can use the four following basis vectors:

$$  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0  \\
0& 0  \\
  \end{bmatrix},  \left[ \begin{array}{c}  0 & 1  \\
0& 0  \\ \end{array} \right],  \left[ \begin{array}{c}  0 & 0  \\
1& 0  \\ \end{array} \right]  ,  \left[ \begin{array}{c}  0 & 0  \\
0& 1  \\ \end{array} \right] $$

The basic problem I have is that I don't know why do we don't start with three basis vectors,or for example five basis vectors? Besides does there exist a fast method to figure our that how to construct the basis vectors? (assuming we know how many of them do we need).For example here the author has defined a family of matrices $V_{i,j}=(m_{rq})=(\delta_{ri}\delta_{jq})\in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ with $1\le i,j\le 2$,but where does that really come from?

I was given a question similar to this one and this takes much time to find such matrices and even I did not know how many matrices do I need which makes it harder.

Comment: The basis is a set of vectors, which are lineary independent and their span is the whole field. You could start with more and then drop all that are not lineary independent and you could start with less, but you would have to add some. I am not sure, how to find a basis of any general vector space (assuming the basis is finite), but for "simple" ones, you can take for each coordinate a vector with one at the coordinate and zeros otherwise

Comment: You must ask "how many degrees of freedom do I have". A 2x2 matrix clearly has 4 degrees of freedom because you have 4 completely independent elements to choose. If you had, say, to deal with symmetric matrices then you would have 3 degrees of freedom.

Comment: @  Michal Adamaszek ,Thanks for that,But I still don't know what is "Degrees of freedom".